# Update Web Service using REST API in Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, rest

I am working with API's and I have to make the update web service. I have tried many ways but I am unable to fetch the desired result.

My domain class is;

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="package")
    public class Package{


        private Integer packageId;
        private String packageName;
        private String description;
        private Date validFrom;
        private Date validUpto;
        public enum Status{Active,Inactive}
        private Status status;

        @JsonBackReference
        private Set<HospitalInformation> hospitalInformation=new HashSet<HospitalInformation>();
//getters and setters
```

My Dao Layer is

```
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public boolean updatePackage(Integer packageId,String packageName,String description,Date validFrom,Date validUpto, Status status) throws Exception {
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx= session.beginTransaction();

        Package packages=hospitalDao.findByPackageId(packageId);

        if(packages!=null){
            packages.setPackageName(packageName);
            packages.setDescription(description);
            packages.setValidFrom(validFrom);
            packages.setValidUpto(validUpto);
            packages.setStatus(status);
            session.saveOrUpdate(packages);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
```

My service layer is

```
@Override
    public boolean updatePackageInfo(Integer packageId,String packageName,String description,Date validFrom,Date validUpto, Status status) throws Exception {

        return updateDao.updatePackage(packageId, packageName, description, validFrom, validUpto, status);
    }
```

My Controller class has compilation errors:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/update")
public class UpdateRecordController {


    @Autowired
    private UpdateService updateService;

    static final Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(RestController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/package", method= RequestMethod.PUT,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Status updatePackageIfo( @RequestParam("Id") Integer Id){
        Package packages=new Package();
    try{
        if(updateService.updatePackageInfo(Id)); //Error {

            return new Status(1,"Successfylly Updated with Package Id "+packages.getPackageId());

        }else{
            return new Status(0,"Failed. Enter a valid packageId");
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new Status(0,e.getMessage());
    }   
    }
}
```

Having checked all the links regarding Update Web Service, I couldn't find anything useful on Google. So i need solution of how to make Update Web service.

Comment: What compilation errors you are getting in Controller?

Comment: I need to pass all the arguments in updatePackageInfo method and not just Id. But if I do that using path variable then i would have to pass it as URL params and not as JSON object. So i want to call the API using and pass JSON object request to it.